# Python Telebot Bad Request: chat not found Телебот не видит ТГ Канал

Tags: python, telebot

нужно подвязать подписку на ТГ канал, -100 в начале айди есть, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот на этой строчке ошибка, что чата не существует (!это канал!)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: а бот-то добавлен в канал?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. В случае с каналом, бота сначала нужно добавить в админы канала